# Why does the grid cell only include first element of div?

Tags: html, css

I made a grid that splits a row from section into three columns:

```css
section {
    grid-area: section;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap:40px;
}
```

And then I made three divs that each have three elements (an image, a heading and a paragraph):

```html
<section>
    <div class="film">
        <img id="film_slika" name="filmovi" alt="filmovi" src="slike/film.jpg"/>
        <h2>Filmovi</h2>
        <p>Preporuke najpopularnijih filmova i klasika - uživanje na malim i velikim ekranima</p>
    </div>
    <div class="film">
        <img id="film_slika" name="knjige" alt="knjige" src="slike/knjige.jpg"/>
        <h2>Knjige</h2>
        <p>Savjeti za raznovrsne knjige - sjajne za čitanje uz kamin ili kišni dan</p>
    </div>
    <div class="film">
        <img id="film_slika" name="knjige" alt="knjige" src="slike/images.jpg"/>
        <h2>Glazba</h2>
        <p>Recenzije raznih glazbenih djela od metala do rapa - imamo sve</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

The grid cell only covers the image which is the first element of the div as you can see on the image:

[image]

Why doesn't grid cover the image, heading and the paragraph when they are all part of a div?

P.S. I've made the height of the image 155% to make it look better that's why grid only covers half of the image.

Comment: The `section` and its styles work great in isolation. I think there's something wrong with `body` or it's class `.grid`. Are you using `float` in your CSS?

Comment: @Vitalii I am not using float, but I do have another grid which I am using for the entire body. That grid has one column and it splits the page into header, section and footer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inspect the styles of the inner elements. Is the height of those DIVs not the same as the cell height?

To me the cell height looks equal to combined height of your heading (H2) and paragraph elements. It might be that your images are somehow taken out of the flow so they are not counted in the container height.

Comment: I checked it out and it seems that specifying the height of the images makes it all go wrong. Thanks for the help, now I know where to start fixing it.